# Struggle without attribute nodes PART 2

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a setup like this:
[image]

And i want to scale UV Sphere depending on its position on Z axis for example. With attribute node that was done in 1 operation and now i cannot find solution, using Separate XYZ and Scale Instances in any configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Four you example, just use the output of the Noise texture to drive the scale of the Instance on Points Node, since it already drives the Z location.  Here's a crude version:

[image: Use the noise texture for scale]

Since you want to keep the sphere shape, plug all the noise value into all three sockets of a Combine XYZ and use that to drive scale.

I didn't put any math in the path, but yo can add math nodes to control the range of scales.

Comment: You don't need the _Combine XYZ_ nodes if you don't want to combine different values. Plugging a float value into a vector socket automatically enters the float into all fields of the vector.

Comment: Sure, but note that I mentioned you could add math nodes. I wanted to make it obvious you could control each dimension's scaling separately.

Answer (score 2):

> As an attentive reader, I can provide you with an answer that, unlike MF's existing answer, actually works. ...

Since you use the node `Noise Texture`, it will be evaluated twice here:

- Once at the point where you use `Set Position` to change the positions of the grid.
- And a second time when you use `Instance on Points` to instantiate your objects at the points.

So you get two different values.

To avoid this problem, the following solutions are available:

### Variant 1

[image]

Here I capture the values of the output *Fac* and store them with `Capture Attribute` into the geometry.

I can then use these values directly when instantiating the objects.

### Variant 2

[image]

Here I query the positions of the points, after these were changed by `Set Position`.

With this I also get the desired result.

*PS: In both examples I also use `Map Range` to control the scaling more precisely. Change the values there according to your taste.*

[image]

---

...And if you do it as shown in the other answer, you will get a nice thing, but the scaling is definitely not dependent on the *Z-position*. Fun in theory, not in practice.

[image]